# Which method is right for designing this game

Tags: android

I am always wondering. If I want to design a Tile game (6 by 6 tiles) where a player can press on one tile  and then the tile moves randomly around the screen untill it hits another specific tile. Then what would be the right way?

1-Create the Tiles as Imageviews and listen for clicks on them and so using the translate animation  I can move the touched tile around randomly (not sure yet how I can detect collision)

2- listen for for the touch methods and checked that the touch coordinates is within the tile coordinate and animate the movement by "drawing" and checking corrdinates.

I am always confused which way to go with when designing games (like that). I know I can use Engines like AndEngine, but I want to avoid it (big learning curve for simple games like that)

Thank you

Comment: ImageView is probably the wrong way to go, as its difficult to exactly place a view at a given coordinates, the idea behind layouts is to do relative layouts that scale to screen size instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `ImageButton` also but `ImageView` works out too, and for collision you can use intersect method of Rect class, you just create a rect for your tile

```
 view.getLocationOnScreen(l);
    int x = l[0];
    int y = l[1];
    int w = view.getWidth();
    int h = view.getHeight();

Rect r=new Rect(x,y,w,h);
```

and then check for collision

```
 if( r.intersect(r2))
```

there are other overload versions of intersect also, refer to the link for more about overloaded ones
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#intersect(android.graphics.Rect)

Comment: What of the shape is not rect?

Comment: it shouldn't have to be a rect, a rect is a bounding box for that shape, you can also make a circle bounding box  for your shape and if you need something very fit for your shape, you can construct a Path for it, but it will decrease performance critically
http://wiki.starling-framework.org/tutorials/basic_collision_detection

Answer (score 0):

You could use processing, it is a relatively simple graphics enviroment for java, the performance is not that great on android through, but it is really simple to get started, can be used in eclipse or with the processing IDE.
http://processing.org/ . The processing IDE also contains alot of examples, it doesnt have any fancy features though so i think that you will prefer using eclipse: http://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/

AndEngine is also relatively easy to use, when you first get the hang of it, plus there is a thriving community, but yeah if you are not that into java yet it can be a steep road to take.

I wouldnt recommend making games with Views, its meant for applications.

Comment: Thank you but as i asked in my questions, I would like to stay away from engines

Comment: I dont understand why you don't want to work with game engines, most of these does NOT have steep learning curves compared to wiritng all the graphics, sound, collision detection etc. etc. yourself. Views are not designed for games, they are meant for application GUI. Also processing is really simple, takes 5 minutes to get started, if you already know java.